# Why can't BigQuery cast this number as an integer?

Tags: casting, google-bigquery

In my query, I have a value formatted as a dollar amount, like this:

```
Coverage_Amount
$10,000
$15,000
null
$2,000
```

So I remove the extra characters and map the null to 0. I get a column back like this:

```
Coverage_Amount
10000
15000
0
2000
```

However, these values are stored as strings, and when I try something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN Coverage_Amount IS NOT NULL THEN INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(query.Coverage_Amount, r'\$|,', ''))
  ELSE 0
END AS Coverage_Amount
```

I get back

```
Coverage_Amount
null
null
0
null
```

The documentation for the `INTEGER()` function says

> Casts expr to a 64-bit integer. Returns NULL if  is a string that doesn't correspond to an integer value.

Is there anything I can do to make BigQuery recognize that these are in fact integers?

Comment: This has been edited since first answers were given; I don't think this really affects the content of the answers and I was just trying to keep things simple for the question, but the above is the full statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you have spaces after 0 at the end of string.

I mean f.e. '&10000 '. So you can try to use RTRIM(value, ' ')

```
SELECT 
  Coverage_Amount, 
  IFNULL(INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(Coverage_Amount, ' '), r'\$|,', '')),0) AS val
FROM   
  (SELECT '$10,000 ' Coverage_Amount)
```

to delete all spaces from the end of string

Then output will be:

```
 Row    Coverage_Amount    val   
 1      $10,000         10000
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue! How strange that BQ can't handle a space for this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Both below versions for BigQuery (respectivelly Legacy SQL and StandardSQL) work and return below result

```sql
Coverage_Amount   val    
10000           10000    
15000           15000    
2000             2000
```

Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  Coverage_Amount, 
  IFNULL(INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(Coverage_Amount, r'\$|,', '')), 0) AS val
FROM   
  (SELECT '10000' Coverage_Amount),
  (SELECT '15000' Coverage_Amount),
  (SELECT '2000' Coverage_Amount)
```

Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '10000' Coverage_Amount UNION ALL
  SELECT '15000' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2000' 
)
SELECT 
  Coverage_Amount, 
  IFNULL(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(Coverage_Amount, r'\$|,', '') AS INT64), 0) AS val
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Obviously, same works for '$15,000' and '$10,000' and '$2,000' etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how your legacy SQL solution is different from mine. I'm still getting nulls back when I do it that way.

Comment: show Coverage_Amount string value for which you are getting null so we will be able to help you. for the examples you provided - it works for both standard and legacy version

Comment: Added more detail to the original post -- sorry about any confusion

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Standard? This worked for me (notice I use the [`CAST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) operator):

```
WITH data as(
select "$10,000" d UNION ALL
select "$15,000" UNION ALL
select "$2,000")

SELECT
d,
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(d, r'\$|,', '') AS INT64) AS Coverage_Amount
FROM data
```

Comment: I've tried that before and gotten the error ```Unrecognized type INT64```

Comment: hmm looks like you are using legacy version indeed (I recommend switching to [standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) as it's way more powerful)

Comment: And please also sign up for the [alpha UI](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform), where standard SQL is the default.

Comment: Probably the correct long-term solution, but in the short term I've inherited a large, complicated query with a lot of subroutines that would need to be changed if I switched.